# Vue JS 1.0.26 Inverts symbols at front-end

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js

I am using [Socialite Social Network Laravel Script](https://codecanyon.net/item/socialite-laravel-social-network-script/17553328) by BootstrapGuru. You can see the demo [here](https://socialite.laravelguru.com/) to understand exacly what's happening. Try to open a chat window with anyone and enter some text and some symbols (for example: "how are you?") You will see the text now is "?how are you":

[image: Example image]

To solve that I am still waiting for the support answer but I am trying to solve it from my end.

I see this on my website's Vue Panel:
[image: Vue component]

And this is how it's on the front end side.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled chat-conversation-list">
    <li class="message-conversation" v-bind:class="[({{ Auth::id() }}==message.user.id) ? 'current-user' : '',  ]" v-for="message in chatBox.conversationMessages.data"> <!-- Messages -->
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
                <a href="#">
                    <img v-bind:src="message.user.avatar" alt="images">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body ">
                <p class="post-text" v-html="message.body"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've also tried to use the same way to get the message:

```
<div class="media-body ">
    <p class="post-text">
        @{{ message.body }}
    </p>
</div>
```

But it is the same. Something important to mention maybe, is that the message is well displayed in the "receiver" window.

So, any clues to show the symbols where should be?

Answer (score 0):

You can override it with some css:

```
.media-body .post-text{direciton: ltr;}
```

Comment: The text is displayed correctly as I mentioned. That's not helping. Thanks anyway.